# React does not render in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, compiler-errors, jsx

I'm new at React.js and I'm trying to render the following code in the browser (Firefox) but the code doesn't render in the browser. Could someone help me please?

React.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM  from "react-dom/client"
const page = (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 1</li>
            <li>Thing 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 3</li>
            <li>Thing 4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 5</li>
            <li>Thing 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
)
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(page)
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I'm using Firefox and visual studio code for Linux mint

Comment: `const page = (` should be `const Page = () => ( ... );`. `ReactDOM.createRoot` should be `const root = ReactDOM.createRoot( ... )`

Answer (score 1):

React uses class or functional components to render the displayed HTML, however, you only provide some JSX in parentheses.

Update your code to use a functional component (the recommended way) instead.

```js
const page = () => {
    return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 1</li>
            <li>Thing 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 3</li>
            <li>Thing 4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 5</li>
            <li>Thing 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
}
```

You may also want to read the React.js docs, as they provide great examples of how to use react.
https://react.dev/

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const page = (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 1</li>
            <li>Thing 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 3</li>
            <li>Thing 4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Thing 5</li>
            <li>Thing 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<>{page}</>);
```

Dom is wrongly imported

Comment: My friend, I tried your solution and it continues the same...